# ReasonML pattern matching error on tuples

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

I am trying to write some game on tezos via ReasonML, stuck with pattern matching on tuples, looks like it does not work

```
let tmp =
    switch (players) {
    | (Some(p), None) =>
      let storage = storage.playerO = Some(Current.source());

      ([], storage);
    | (None, Some(_)) =>
      let storage = storage.playerX = Some(Current.source());

      ([], storage);
    | (_, _) => failwith("No empty slots")
    };
```

I'm getting "Bad pattern" compile error. But it seems like valid Reason syntax.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Tezos Stack Exchange. Could you please provide the exact error message you get ? thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, Liquidity does not implement deep pattern-matching as in OCaml or Reason. You have to match only one level (constructor or tuple) at a time. We hope to be able to improve that in later versions.